# Django Allauth Ignoring Adapter

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-allauth

Allauth signin keeps showing, despite adding adapter. Following allauth documentation on Overriding the allauth signin, I created an adapter.py in my app (accounts) with:

```
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter

class NoNewUsersAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def is_open_for_signup(self, request):
       return False
```

I added to my settings file:

```
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'accounts.adapter.NoNewUsersAccountAdapter'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the `DefaultSocialAccountAdapter` by importing it from `from allauth.socialaccount.adapter import DefaultSocialAccountAdapter`.Don't forget to include it in `settings.py` as `SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER ='python.path.to.your.NormalAdapter'`